i want text of label when it in datalist
in .net , i have a problem . i want the text of label in datalist and i cant use id because its in datalist and its id is not available in c# or js .i don't can use for to find lable in datalist my label because i don't now user click to Which linkbutton.
. this is my code :
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="click" runat="server" ID="label" ><%# Eval("Id")%></asp:LinkButton>

and in c sharp i want when user click, the text of label saved to variable
i thought id is works when element in datalist but it is not correct.

That looks like a. Net framework label   so are you sure this is .core cs framework? And this don't look like MVC, but looks like webforms? So all of your tags look wrong except for asp.net. What kind of project is this and what version of. Net framework are you using here?

What version of .net are you using?

You can simply create an event to know that user click on LinkButton or not.
In .aspx file:-
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Click Here</asp:LinkButton> 

In .aspx.cs file
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Label1.Text = "User click here.";  
} 

You can create click event on each and every LinkButton as per your requirement.
I hope this helps you.
